# Display data in seed file to a show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm very new to rails. What I'm trying to do is display info i have in a seed file to my views/show page. This is some of my seed file, it's just made up organizations for a school project I'm doing.

```
`Organization.create(
name: "St. John's church",
location: "222 Bathurst st.",
description: "Church"
)

Organization.create(
name: "Women's Shelter Toronto",
location: "777 Yonge St.",
description: "Womens Shelter"
)

Organization.create(
name: "Toronto Homeless Shelter",
location: "111 King St.",
description: "Shelter"
)`
```

here is my show page

```
<h1>Organization#show</h1>


<div class="container">
  <h1>Organization:</h1>
  <%= @organization.name %>
</div><br>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Description:</h1>
</div><br>
```

and organization controller

```
def show
    @organization = Organization.all
  end

  def new
    @organization = Organization.new
  end

  def create
    @organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
    if @organization.save
      redirect_to root_url

    else
      render "new"
    end
  end


  private
  def organization_params
    params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :description, :location)
   end
  end
```

This very basic i know i'm just learning.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should probably use use `create!` in your seed file so that if any of your creates fail you will see an exception flagged.

Second, what you are using as a `show` action should more likely be the `#index` action in your controller as that is the `rails` convention. When you stray from `rails` conventions your programming life gets a whole lot heavier and slower.

As an interim manual test you can run between `first and second` is this: After your seed file has been run, you can do things like:

```
rails console
Organization.count
Organization.all
```

to verify that your data is seeded properly.

At that point, you may find implementing and debugging your `show`, `edit` and `new` actions more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @caprison Be sure to choose an answer as "correct," that gives the responder reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the [seeds.rb](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) file is to populate the database after the first time it's created.

After you do that, you can display the newly created data in your database on the page using [Active Record](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data).

I see 2 possible problems here:

1. You don't need the `` at the beginning and end of the seeds.rb file.
2. You didn't run `rake db:seed` - This command takes the seeds.rb file and actually creates the records in the database.

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

In your OrganizationsController#show method you are setting @organization to a list of all organization entries in your database.  @organization.name is therefore not a valid method.  You can do one of two things.  If you only want to show one organization on the show page, which would be typical, you would have to find that organization somehow.  When a user requests a show page for a particular organization he typically does so in a RESTful manner, that is through /organizations/:id, where :id is the id of the particular organization he or she would like to show.  In your controller try:

```
def show
  @orginazation = Organization.find(params[:id])
end
```

params[] is how Rails passes information between views and controllers.  In this case params[:id] would be 1 if the user requested /organizations/1.  Your controller would then go to the database and find the organization whose id was 1.

Now if you want to show a list of all organizations you would do so typically in the #index method.  Something like this.

```
def index
  @organizations = Organization.all
end
```

Then you would have an `index.html.erb` file in which you would iterate through the @organizations, like so.

```
<% @organizations.each do |organization| %>
  <%= organization.name %>
  <%= organization.location %>
  <%= organization.description %>
<% end %>
```

This way when your user requests /organizations, he or she will see a listing of all the organizations in your database.

Edit: Your post also suggests that your controller is called `OrganizationController`, it should be plural, `OrganizationsController` and the associated filename should be `organizations_controller.rb`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I used your suggestions but I'm getting an error now Couldn't find "Organization with 'id'=show"

Comment: So you are navigating to /organizations/1 for example?  If anything that should return an error saying "Couldn't find Organizations with 'id'=1.  If that's the case your seeds are not actually in your database.

Comment: To add to my above comment, one way to test if your seeds are actually populated in your db would be similar to what @Greg Tarsa recommended below.  Run a rails console by typing `rails c` or `rails console` in your terminal.  Then type `Organization.first`  this should return the first Organization object in your database if one exists.  If it doesn't you know your seeds are not in your database.  If that's the case try running rake db:migrate in your terminal to populate them.

Comment: Glad I could be of service.